# Does English have different words for different-looking owls?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

French has *le hibou* and *la chouette* for owls with and without little tufty ears, German has *der Kauz*, *der Uhu* and *die Eule* for a similar (but not identical) distinction, Spanish has *la lechuza* and *el búho*.

Does English have a similar words for owls that look different (not the species name, but based on some shared characteristic)?

Comment: No. in English an owl is an owl. The species of owl being the only difference. i.e Barn Owl, Brown Owl, etc.

Comment: Some years ago a friend's husband, knowing I understood French, asked me the difference between _le hibou_ and _la chouette_, and I had to look it up. The only tufted owls we have in the UK are the long-eared and short-eared.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) it shows no signs of reasonable research (a quick look for synonyms / classmates in a thesaurus0, but mainly because (b) it is almost certain to generate lists (all right, has already generated lists) which belong on a site dedicated to ornithology rather than on a site geared to standard English usages. Despite the attractiveness of _Andaman Boobook_.

Comment: Sort of yes, but not really, no. Looking at [a list of owls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Strigiformes_by_population) a small number are named 'boobook' (presumably cognate with FR 'hibou' and maybe GE 'uhu'). However, this is the first time in my not short life that I have heard that word, so I suspect that few people except for birders would recognize it.

Comment: Also can you edit your question to include the research you did on a thesaurus or wikipedia at the least?

Comment: @Mitch I am puzzled by this request: the question is either interesting and relevant or not. I think it is manifestly not a trivial question to research, and the internet record of the answers it receives will save someone in future that effort. The notion that (especially) new users have to prove themselves beyond asking questions that conform to the rules of the site is one of the less appealing characteristics of this particular Stack Exchange site.

Comment: No, but "horned owl" can be used for any of several species of owl that has earlike tufts.  See [Encyclopaedia Britannica: Horned owl](https://www.britannica.com/animal/horned-owl) *any of 17 species of owls with hornlike tufts of feathers on the head.* and also [MERRIAM-WEBSTER: horned owl](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horned%20owl): *any of various owls having conspicuous tufts of feathers on the head*.

Comment: There are five British species of owl, the barn owl, tawny owl, little owl, long eared owl, and short eared owl. The two "eared" owls have ear tufts. However for most people in the UK "owl" means the tawny owl, which is the only one they are likely to hear (note, hear, not see!) making its "too-wit, too-woo" call while hunting at night.

Comment: @user234902 I think this is a very interesting question. But there are also standards established over the years for users of this site that they at least attempt some minimal research first and tell us about it so that we don't repeat it. Even if no other SE sites share these standards, they are the existing standards here now. Some homes you take off your shoes before entering, others you don't; it's just courtesy to do like the homeowners do.

Comment: The bit about German is plain wrong, and in more ways than I have room to elaborate upon. But in short, an Uhu is an Eule, and so is a Kauz. It has nothing to do with ears, most Germans use them completely interchangeably, and when pressed, will at best tell you that one is just the male and the other the female of the same species. (Not to mention that nobody uses Kauz to begin with, except in the meaning "weird fellah".) This paired with @Kate's comment above, as well as with what my French, Spanish and Peruvian neighbors tell me, leaves me thinking this question frankly has no premise.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I invite you to reread your comment and assess whether it might come across as needlessly condescending and unwelcoming to new users of this site. The question may not have been a great one, but it was upvoted and received several helpful and respectful answers from other users. Since we’re being frank, I now have no interest in engaging with this site, where in other circumstances I might have felt I wanted to improve, broaden and develop my participation, as I have with other topics.

Answer (score 4):

**No,** English has no specific word for owls based on this characteristic.

**Terms for this feature in owls:**

- Ear tuft [[wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_tuft), most widely-used
- Plumicorns [[Merriam Webster Dictionary]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plumicorn), in zoology
- Egret [[Oxford English Dictionary]](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00004857), although this term more commonly refers to the species Egrets

  - *A tuft of feathers such as that borne by the Egret and some other birds; a spray of gems, or similar ornament, worn on the head.*
- Horn [[Wordnik]](https://www.wordnik.com/words/horn), when referring specifically to birds

  - *Specifically— A feeler; a tentacle; an antenna; an ovipositor; also, the tuft of feathers upon the head of sundry birds, resembling a horn; a plumicorn, as that of various owls.*
- Corniplume [[Free Dictionary]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Corniplume), rarely

**So what does an English-speaker call the collective of owls with this feature?**

"Owls with ear tufts" (or any synonym you prefer) is clearest.

You will also be understood if you refer to "Tufted owls" or "Horned owls", but this may give the implication you are referring to specific species such as the Long-Tufted Screech Owl or the Great Horned Owl depending on context.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, English has no specific (single) words for different-looking owls. However, we use compound names for different-looking owls.

According to [The Spruce](https://www.thespruce.com/owl-species-list-385440), there are more than 225 owl species in the world, divided into two families.

> Barn owls with their distinct heart-shaped facial disks make up the **Tytonidae** family, while all other owl species are in the **Strigidae** or *typical owl family*.
>
> **Alphabetical List of Owl Species Sorted by Common Name:**
>
> Names with * -> Considered threatened or vulnerable due to population decreases and growing survival threats.
>
> Names with** -> Listed as endangered and in critical danger of extinction if conservation is not implemented (Classifications by BirdLife International).
>
> ### Tytonidae Owls
>
> - African Grass-Owl (Tyto capensis)
> - Ashy-Faced Owl (Tyto glaucops)
> - Australian Masked-Owl (Tyto novaehollandiae)
> - Common Barn-Owl (Tyto alba)
> - **Congo Bay-Owl (Phodilus prigoginei)
> - Eastern Grass-Owl (Tyto longimembris)
> - *Golden Masked-Owl (Tyto aurantia)
> - Greater Sooty-Owl (Tyto tenebricosa)
> - Lesser Sooty-Owl (Tyto multipunctata)
> - *Madagascar Red Owl (Tyto soumagnei)
>   *Minahassa Masked-Owl (Tyto inexspectata)
> - Oriental Bay-Owl (Phodilus badius)
> - Seram Masked-Owl (Tyto almae)
>   Sri Lanka Bay-Owl (Phodilus assimilis)
> - Sulawesi Masked-Owl (Tyto rosenbergii)
> - *Taliabu Masked-Owl (Tyto nigrobrunnea)

> ### Strigidae Owls
>
> - African Barred Owlet (Glaucidium capense)
> - African Long-Eared Owl (Asio abyssinicus)
> - African Scops-Owl (Otus senegalensis)
> - African Wood-Owl (Strix woodfordii)
> - Akun Eagle-Owl (Bubo leucostictus)
> - *Albertine Owlet (Glaucidium albertinum)
> - Amazonian Pygmy-Owl (Glaucidium hardyi)
> - Andaman Boobook (Ninox affinis)
> - Andaman Scops-Owl (Otus balli)
> - Andean Pygmy-Owl (Glaucidium jardinii)
> - **Anjouan Scops-Owl (Otus capnodes)
> - **Annobon Scops-Owl (Otus feae)
> - Arabian Scops-Owl (Otus pamelae)
> - Asian Barred Owlet (Glaucidium cuculoides)

[[The Spruce]](https://www.thespruce.com/owl-species-list-385440)

[18 Owl Species With Irresistible Faces
and English names By Jaymi Heimbuch - TreeHugger](https://www.treehugger.com/owl-species-with-irresistible-faces-4864301)

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of owl.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl):

> Owls are divided into two families: the true (or typical) owl family, Strigidae, and the barn-owl family, Tytonidae.

but there is no common distinction.

The situation in French, German, Spanish, etc is similar to the English names for the members of the bird family of thrushes: there is a blackbird, a robin, a redstart, a fieldfare, a redwing, etc. but they are all essentially thrushes.

Comment: Note that these days robins are classed as Old World flycatchers and not thrushes.

Comment: @Showsni:  Unless you're in North America, in which case [a robin is still a thrush.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_robin)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no, In English an owl is an owl, there are no other pronunciation for it. Here is a bit more detail.

Referenced from [owl pages](https://www.owlpages.com/owls/articles.php?a=96#:%7E:text=The%20word%20owl%20originated%20in,unique%20call%20of%20an%20Owl.)

> The word owl originated in early European languages. In old Norse, an Owl was known as "ugla", and in old German, it was "uwila". Both of these words may have been created as sounds that described the unique call of an Owl

So the word `owl` seems to have been created to specifically describes the animal, by the sound it makes.

I will also drift off the point of the word owl a bit, simply to explain a bit about languages and the use of words and where they derived from.

This is the case in a lot of languages that derived from other languages. In most African languages, objects are named by the sound it makes or by what it looks like. The also use amend words from other languages by simply adding a letter to it. A very good example is in South Africa in the Zulu and Tswana language, the word `Corona` is simply transformed to `iCorona` which represents the way they construct their language.

Words across many languages were also adopted and adapted, even though a direct translation of the word from its derived language is not the same thing. Examples:

In English `lemon`is the sour fruit with a yellow skin found on trees during fall and winter. The Language Afrikaans adapted the word and made it `lemoen` but a `lemoen` is not a `lemon` but instead it is an `orange`. In Afrikaans, a `Lemon` is actually called a `suur lemoen` which directly translates to `sour lemon`.

That is why owl in other languages can have various words for the species, because these words better explain the difference between the birds, where instead in English, the difference of the bird is explained by the type of owl.
i.e a Barn Owl is called that because it is mostly seen in and around barns on farms where it feeds of mice that nests in the "organized chaos" of sheds and barns.

Comment: The orange color is named after the fruit, and not the other way round. As indeed demonstrated by the very fact that it's *orange* and no longer *norange*. That could only happen because it was a noun first, and only later an adjective.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thank you, I will rectify that in the answer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I actually removed it as it no longer makes the point I had if I changed it. Thanks :)